# Writing a csv file in Python 3

Tags: python

I have three lists `a`, `b`, and `c` that I would like to write to a csv file as columns. I'm having trouble (since `data` has these as rows) and also with writing the csv. Here is what I have.

```
import csv

my_output=open('myfile.csv','wb')
mywriter=csv.writer(csv_out)

a=[1,3,5,7]
b=[2,4,6,8]
c=[0,0,0,0]
data=[a,b,c]

for item in data:
    mywriter.writerow(item)
my_output.close()
```

Comment: Where is `csv_out` defined? Do you mean `my_output`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Python: CSV write by column rather than row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155106/python-csv-write-by-column-rather-than-row)

Comment: yeah, I've changed it to my_output.  Now I'm getting an error:

Comment: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores data in [Row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

You have to break the problem down first:

```
a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [2,4,6,8]
c = [0,0,0,0]
data = [a,b,c]

for i in range(len(data[0])):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        print data[j][i],
    print ''
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 0 
3 4 0 
5 6 0 
7 8 0
```

### Putting it all together:

```
import csv

my_output = open('myfile.csv', 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(my_output)

a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [2,4,6,8]
c = [0,0,0,0]
data = [a,b,c]

for i in range(len(data[0])):
    row = [data[j][i] for j in range(len(data))]
    mywriter.writerow(row)

my_output.close()
```

#### Shorter (safer) version:

```
import csv

my_output = open('myfile.csv', 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(my_output)

a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [2,4,6,8]
c = [0,0,0,0]
data = [a,b,c]

for row in zip(*data):
    mywriter.writerow(row)

my_output.close()
```

See [`zip([iterable, ...])`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) for information on this built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create variable `data`. Use built-in function zip. It makes an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

```
for item in zip(a, b, c):
    mywriter.writerow(item)
```

Documentation for reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip