# Python CSV output two rows instead of two column

Tags: python, csv

I am outputing a dictionary, see the code below. but, the out creates two rows. instead of two columns.

```
with open("<location of file>"+str(report_date)+".csv", 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(output_list.keys())
    w.writerow(output_list.values())
```

Excel Output:

```
Col 1 row 1, col 2, row 1, col 3 row 1
Col 1 row 2, col2 row 2, col 3, row 2
```

I would like to see the output as two columns:
column 1 all the way down for the dictionary Keys
column 2 all the way down for the dictionary values

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Whitespace is mostly non-optional in Python

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155106/python-csv-write-by-column-rather-than-row

Comment: Also, please provide a sample input file and fix your sample output. It looks wildly inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are outputting two rows because you are telling it to output two rows. That is what `writerow` does if you call it twice. You need to iterate over the individual items if you want to output one row per item:

```
w = csv.writer(f)
for item in output_list.items():
    w.writerow(item)
```

`item` will be a two-element tuple that contains the key and the value.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I see the issue now. Is it possible to have no blank row between each row? The output contains a blank row between the data. @Mad Physicist

Comment: @OPM_OK. I can't answer that question unless you provide a sample `output_list` that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also, it is traditional to select an answer that fixes your problem.