# Move pointer to other column to write CSV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wan to add a column to my file in the beginning then paste the data from other file.
When I do so, I am able to write data in 1st column but when I write data from the file, it does not start from 2nd column rather continues in first.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKtCz.png)

How it shows, eg.:

```
1 #new data(1-5)
2
3
4
5
a #data from other file(a-d)
b
c
d
```

What I want:

```
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d
5  e
```

Code:

```py
wr = csv.writer(d,lineterminator='\r') # filename is d
wr.writerow(field) #field contains list of columns
for i in range(1,152):
    wr.writerow(['test'])
  #I want something here to point to next column
wr.writerow(split_data) #split_data contains data that I want to initialise from 2nd column
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rynYRX8w

Comment: Please add the code formatted to your question and not in a link in the comments. That way it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow. I've added the code in my question.

Comment: You're adding a row, but you want a column. I'd suggest having a proper look at the [`csv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155106/python-csv-write-by-column-rather-than-row

Answer (score 0):

Files do not really have "columns", they are just a string of bytes from beginning to end.  Also, filesystems generally do not support any form of "insert" operation, only "overwrite" and "append."  Therefore, you will need to read the file in, build the output you want, and write all of it.  You simply cannot "write one column."