# Save output in a new column of input file python3

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-columns, numpy-ndarray

a numpy array of 40 elements were used to calculate the value of another variable m in a loop. Now, if i have to save the result of calculations in the same file in next column, how to do it? 
Also since 'mv' is defined as an empty array,'[]', i wanted to know if mv.append inside loop will work?

```
import numpy as np
file = input("Input Filename: ")
v = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter= "\n")
c = float(input("correction for mv: "))

a = 0
mv = []

while a < len(v):
    mv[a] = v[a] - c
    mv.append(mv[a])
    print (mv[a])
    f.write('\t' + str(mv[a] + '\n')
    a = a+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i wanted to know if mv.append inside loop will work?

Yes, it's an array built-in method.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155106/python-csv-write-by-column-rather-than-row)