# Writing multiple sets of lists into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have multiple lists:

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d]
list2 = [e,f,g,h]
list3 = [i,j,k,l]
```

I want to write and save them into one csv file, such that list1 is column 1, list2 is column 2, etc. I found this code, but it makes list1 into row 1, list2 into row 2, etc. which is not what I want.

```
import csv

csvData = [['Person', 'Age'], ['Peter', '22'], ['Jasmine', '21'], ['Sam', '24']]

with open('person.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(csvData)

csvFile.close()
```

Opening the csv file gives:

```
Person,Age
Peter,22
Jasmine,21
Sam,24
```

I want it to be

```
Person, Peter, Jasmine, Sam, ...
Age, 22, 21, 24, ...
```

Is there a way to do this? I took Python years ago, so I vaguely remember things. Also, isn't there a way to write all your lists into one csv file and save it in a directory? How does this go again? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before writing csvData to the file. Instead write new_csvData.

`new_csvData = zip(*csvData)
writer.writerows(new_csvData)`

The question is a little different however here is the link for more infrmation: [Python: CSV write by column rather than row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155106/python-csv-write-by-column-rather-than-row)