# Save list with each value in new row CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to save a set of emails into a csv file with each email below the other like this

```
example@gmail.com
example2@gmail.com
```

But instead I get them all in the same row and next to eachother.

I have tried looking at the CSV module and many other questions to no avail, hoping the solution is easy
Here is my current code for saving to a CSV File, each email is saved next to each other instead of below.

```
with open('emaillist.csv', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(emails)

        f.close()
```

Comment: Whatever `emails` is, you should probably be iterating over it and writing a row for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
with open('emaillist.csv', 'w', ) as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    for email in emails:
        wr.writerow([email])
myfile.close()
```

Duplicate of [Python: CSV write by column rather than row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155106/python-csv-write-by-column-rather-than-row)