# Write list to csv with new column in for-loop

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to write a list to csv file in a for loop, and each time at a different column.
for example, the first iteration I generate a list = [1,2,3,4,5], and the second iteration I have list = [1,2,3]. I want the output .csv to look something like:

```
col1.     col2
---------------
  1        1
  2        2
  3        3
  4
  5
```

I got the following code:

```
## open csv file
with open(pic_path + 'file.csv', "w+") as my_csv:

for loop:
    (## do something.... and generate a list)
    
    ## write list as column to csv file
    csvWriter = csv.writer(my_csv)
        for val in list:
            csvWriter.writerows([val])
```

The output instead looks like this:

```
col1
-----
  1       
  2        
  3        
  4
  5
  1
  2
  3
```

What the above does is it keeps continuing to write the first column and it does not change to a new column at the next iteration. How can tell python to do so?

Comment: This might be beyond what the Python CSV Writer provides, one workaround would be to read-in the CSV append your additional column and re-write.

The csv doesn't really see columns, it sees rows with value separators and a line feed to start a new row... ( Or variations on that format)

Here is a similar question with various hacks to achieve what you are asking
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155106/python-csv-write-by-column-rather-than-row

Answer (score 0):

A easy way is to use pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
_csv = pd.read_csv("file.csv") #read your csv file
_csv.to_csv("new_file.csv") #write your data in the new csv file

# you can write by column too
_csv["col1"].to_csv("other_new_file.csv") #write col1 in the other new csv file
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a list of lists
2. Transpose the list of lists using zip,numpy or any other method
3. Then print it the standard way in csvwriter